# What kind of PayPal sandbox account is necessary for Express Payments rails module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm signing up for a PayPal sandbox account and there is no option listed for "Express Payment Gateway".  There IS an option for this on the non sandbox PayPal site.

I really wish these guys would simplify their product offering!  We know that it is NOT Website Payments Standard or Pro.

This functionality is working in production with a live PayPal just not in the sandbox.

We keep receiving an "You are not signed up to accept payment for digitally delivered goods" which other questions and answers indicate we do not have an Express Payments option on our sandbox account.

Thanks!

My choices when creating a sandbox account are:

- Website Payments Standard
- Website Payments Pro
- Virtual Terminal
- PayPal as an Additional Payment Option
- Email Payments
- PayPal for your EBay Business
- Payflow Gateway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log a ticket at https://www.paypal.com/mts and they'll enable it for you.
For what it's worth, the product you're trying to use is: **Digital Goods for Express Checkout**.
Express Checkout itself is available by default on all accounts, but that team can enable Digital Goods on your Sandbox account.

Comment: I did this for my company sandbox account almost a week ago, and other than a clarification for the account email address, I have got no response whatsoever... how long will this product take to enable?  EDIT: I got the email saying it was enabled less than 2 minutes after posting this!  Unbelievable....

Answer (score 2):

In the actual test user creation section of the sandbox there are now just three options (for pre-configured, which is what you probably want).  Choose the middle option: Merchant.  Choose to create a pre-configured test user, choose Merchant, and it will be set up with Digital Goods enabled.  (Don't choose Website Payments Pro).

One of the technical support people mentioned this on the forum on x.com where most people are requesting their sandbox test users be enabled for Digital Goods.

Similar Question:
[PayPal Digital Goods Error on login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734718/paypal-digital-goods-error-on-login/9679052#9679052)